# Задача с покупкой продуктов

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Падает задача выдавая Runtime error. При этом на тестовом примере работает правильно. Подскажите где может быть ошибка в коде.

> Жена отправила мужа в торговый центр покупать продукты. Муж должен купить там ровно K продуктов. В этом торговом центре есть N магазинов. В каждом магазине есть ровно 3 продукта. Но из каждого магазина муж может купить максимум 2 продукта. Задача мужа купить жене K продуктов за минимальную цену.
>
> **Вводные данные:** Первая строка содержит целое число T количество тестов. Первая строка каждого тестового примера содержит два числа N и K, разделенные пробелом (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000),(1 ≤ K ≤ 2N). Далее следуют N строк. Каждая строка содержит 3 числа разделенных пробелами обозначающие цену продуктов в магазине. (1 ≤ P ≤ 10^6)
>
> **Вывод:** Для каждого тестового примера печатайте одну строку, содержащую единственное целое число, обозначающее минимальную цену, необходимую для покупки точно продуктов K из данных магазинов при выполнении вышеуказанного условия.
>
> **Примеры Ввода/Вывода:**
>
> ```
> +------------------+-------------------+
> | стандартный ввод | стандартный вывод |
> +------------------+-------------------+
> | 1                | 7                 |
> | 3 4              |                   |
> | 1 10 300         |                   |
> | 4 5 6            |                   |
> | 1 100 1          |                   |
> +------------------+-------------------+
> ```

В своем коде я сначала записываю в массив цены продуктов, потом сортирую их от меньшего к большему и записываю в финальный массив z только 2 наименьших. А дальше просто сортирую уже весь массив z и плюсую нужное K количество продуктов к сумме (sum). Как понимаю runtime error выдает при работе с большими цислами, но не могу понять почему ведь в теории должен работать.

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long long int xx, n, k, t[9000], z[9000], tem, sum=0, cn=0;
int main()
{
    cin >> xx;
    for(int i=0;i<xx;i++)
    {
        cin >> n >> k;
        for(int q=0;q<n;q++)
        {
            for(int y=0;y<3;y++)
            {
                cin >> t[y];
            }
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                for(int r=0;r<2;r++)
                {
                    if(t[r]>t[r+1])
                    {
                        tem = t[r+1];
                        t[r+1] = t[r];
                        t[r] = tem;
                    }
                }
            }
            z[cn] = t[0];
            cn++;
            z[cn] = t[1];
            cn++;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<2*n;j++)
        {
            for(int r=0;r<(2*n)-1;r++)
            {
                if(z[r]>z[r+1])
                {
                    tem = z[r+1];
                    z[r+1] = z[r];
                    z[r] = tem;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int y=0;y<k;y++)
        {
            sum+=z[y];
        }
        cout << sum << endl;
        sum = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И где именно в вашем вопросе приведен пример, на котором задача падает???

Comment: @AnT задача падает на последнем тесте где огромное количество T тестов, с большими числами K и N, из-за чего я не могу скопировать этот тест.

Comment: @AnT вопрос как можно сократить или ускорить работу кода.

Comment: "Ускорить работу кода" можно путем применения более разумных алгоритмов сортировки. У вас реализован тормозной "пузырек", причем реализован "грубо", что делает его еще медленнее.

Comment: Задача поставлена не правильно:  а если во всех магазинах он купит один и тот же продукт? Ведь дело не только в цене, но и в разновидности продуктов....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша программа должна последовательно решать множество совершенно независимых задач (`xx` штук). При этом при переходе от одной задачи к следующей вы не переинициализируете свои переменные. Например, где обнуление переменной `cn` при переходе к следующей задаче? Переменная `cn` никогда не обнуляется, что рано или поздно приводит к вылету за пределы массива `z` и падению программы.

Разумеется, более общий вопрос: почему ваши переменные объявлены как глобальные??? Что за странная манера и откуда она пошла? Если бы они у вас были объявлены более разумным способом - локально - то и проблема с правильной инициализацией переменных скорее всего бы не возникла.

Comment: спасибо огромное, переписал код по вашему совету вот так вот - https://pastebin.com/2BU0ZTUg и он прошел!

Comment: даже не пришлось QuickSort использовать вместо BubbleSort, хотя уже был готов)

Comment: @rengetsu: Ну если уж на то пошло, то все ваши переменные, кроме `t`, должны быть объявлены *внутри* "главного" цикла по `i`. Тогда бы вам и переинициализировать их не пришлось. Именно это я и имел в виду выше. А сейчас у вас разница с глобальными переменными невелика. А лучше было бы вообще вынести решение одной проблемы в отдельную функцию.